# Where does notepad++ store style configurator settings?

Tags: styles, notepad++

I downloaded and modified a style file and placed it in the Notepad++ themes folder. I was able to select it and have it update the style as expected. I then went to `Settings -> Style Configurator` and changed the font of COMMENT of language VHDL to MS Gothic, hit save, and closed and exited Notepad++. I am able to relaunch Notepad++ and still see the change (I'm running Notepad++ in admin mode on Win7).

The only file that I can see a new timestamp on is my XML theme file, but I don't see MS Gothic anywhere in the file. Where is this information being stored? It is overriding the settings from my theme file. I also checked `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\stylers.xml` but I don't see it there either.

I realize I can change it back through the GUI, but I'd like to know how to get back to my original theme without selecting every style in the language manually (as I've made multiple changes). If I could edit (or delete) a file, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Look in your `%APPDATA%\Notepad++` folder, specifically for the `stylers.xml` file.

Comment: Hi Adam, There are no changes to stylers.xml. I noticed that if I forget to run Notepad++ in admin mode, the changes I make don't persist for the next run, so that tells me it's storing them somewhere in the install folder. But as I said above, the only file I see that has a new timestamp is my theme file. I search for "MS" and for "Gothic" and don't see either string there.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. If you change the default theme, then it's the `stylers.xml` file. Otherwise, it will attempt to edit the theme file in the `Program Files\Notepad++` folder. If it can't (because of permissions) then the changes will not persist after closing the application.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me with this. I had assumed it worked the way you're describing. The confusing part is that when I'm in admin mode, the changes DO persist, yet I don't see the font change in my theme file, even though the timestamp clearly says that file changed upon my saving the settings. I've worked around this by copying the contents of my theme file to stylers.xml and just using that instead.

Comment: That's just...weird. What version are you using?

Comment: Now that I know it's supposed to work the way you describe, I agree. The version is 6.0.

Comment: I've not used that recent a version, so there may be behaviors that have changed between our two versions. Your solution should be fine, though.

Comment: I had the same issue.  For me the `\themes` directory was lost on my user account's `%APPDATA%\NotePad++` directory.  I copied the directory over and reset NotePad++ and that fixed it up for me.

Answer (score 12):

1. Uninstall Notepad++
2. Reinstall it again, but this time check the first box, the one that says "Don't use  %APPDATA%..... "
3. Enjoy.

The reason is that Notepad++ install all the files at administrator profile, if you are using another user then you are screw, it will not work properly, you have to run it always as an administrator so it can work properly. To avoid this, just do as i said.

Answer (score 10):

If files are going to APPDATA, then you can create a folder called "themes" and then inside that place your new xml themes. Then close and reopen notepad++ and you should see your new style in the "Select theme:" drop down. Whatever you named the file should be what appears in the dropdown

Answer (score 8):

Just as a complement to the other answers, if you made the changes on another theme than the default theme (`stylers.xml`) then your changes are saved to
`%APPDATA%\Notepad++\themes\TheThemeYouModified.xml`.

For example, if you modified the choco theme, then look for the `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\themes\choco.xml`.

You will also find a choco.xml in the C`:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\themes` but this one is not where your changes are saved.

I tried Rbastardo answer, but even when I check "Don't use %APPDATA%....." when installing Notepad++, the changes are still saved in  %APPDATA%.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows 10 the path to add the new theme is :

```
C:\Users\NAME-OF-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\themes
```

[image]

stylers.xml is located one director/ folder above the themes :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone in the future, if you installed Notepad++ via Scoop then look for your themes directory here:

```
D:\Users\yourusername\scoop\persist\notepadplusplus\themes
```