# Is it possible in Notepad++ to associate a file extension with a dot in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notepad++, erb

I'm really trying to associate the various `.erb` filetypes. I would like to be able to associate `.css.erb` and `.scss.erb` with CSS, `.html.erb` with HTML, and `.js.erb` with JavaScript. Associating all `.erb` files with HTML does fine for HTML files themselves, but it doesn't work very well for JavaScript, CSS, or SCSS.

I've tried putting `css.erb`, etc. in the "User ext.:" box within the Style Configurator dialog, but it doesn't seem to pick up on the files properly.

I'm skeptical that this is possible, because I imagine the engine matches from the last `.` to the end of the filename rather than, e.g., something like `filename.endswith(ext)`, but I thought it worthwhile to ask if anyone has found a way to make it work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are right. I tried to change manually the `langs.xml` and had the same results as you.

Comment: extension in Windows is the last dot and onwards, so unless Notepadd++ didn't use the native extension returning function, or used a regex that goes from the end backwards to the first dot, it won't work

Comment: @nrathaus It wouldn't be hard to take a given filename and, like I mentioned, test with `.endswith(ext)` or something similar. I think a regex is the completely wrong thing to use in this case and I really hope that npp doesn't use regexes to test their file extensions.

Comment: They don't use regex, you could probably provide them with a patch and improve their code if you want, it is opensource you know. You could also compile your own version.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this does not work, would be nice to set .ext.in to be treated like .ext by default. For now I choose Language each time I open one.

Answer (score 1):

[image: CSS and ERB File Extension Screencap]
Use the following process:

- Open a new file
- Input the desired content
- Use <kbd>File=>Save</kbd> to save it as the desired MIME type, for instance `foo.css` for CSS
- Use <kbd>File=>Save As</kbd> to save it again as the desired ERB file extension, for instance `foo.css.erb`

After using the [Style Configurator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983048/), I have the following in the `stylers.xml` file in the folder where the Notepadd++ executable is installed:

```
<LexerType ext="css.erb" desc="CSS" name="css">

<WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="000000" styleID="0"/>

<WordsStyle name="TAG" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="Batang" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="0000FF" styleID="1"/>

<WordsStyle name="CLASS" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="FF0000" styleID="2"/>

<WordsStyle name="PSEUDOCLASS" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="FF8000" styleID="3"/>

<WordsStyle name="UNKNOWN_PSEUDOCLASS" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="FF8080" styleID="4"/>

<WordsStyle name="OPERATOR" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="000000" styleID="5"/>

<WordsStyle name="IDENTIFIER" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="8080C0" styleID="6" keywordClass="instre1"/>

<WordsStyle name="UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="000000" styleID="7"/>

<WordsStyle name="VALUE" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="000000" styleID="8"/>

<WordsStyle name="COMMENT" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="008000" styleID="9"/>

<WordsStyle name="ID" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="0080FF" styleID="10"/>

<WordsStyle name="IMPORTANT" fontSize="" fontStyle="1" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="FF0000" styleID="11"/>

<WordsStyle name="DIRECTIVE" fontSize="" fontStyle="0" fontName="" bgColor="FFFFFF" fgColor="0080FF" styleID="12"/>

</LexerType>
```

You can add more for each variation of erb by copying the model from `stylers.model.xml` and following the pattern.

**References**

- [Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts: Lists of default mouse and keyboard shortcuts for Notepad++ and some plugins](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)
- [Plugin Development: How to develop a plugin or a lexer](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Development)
- [Macros: Sequences of actions, aka macros](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros)

Comment: For me at least, this does not work; as soon as it's saved as `*.css.erb` it loses its syntax highlighting (tested with with N++ v6.9.2)

Comment: @kenbellows I tested again and added a screen capture.

Comment: In my experience, it only keeps its syntax highlighting as long as the file is open. If you close the file and open it again, or open another `.css.erb` file, its language association is not maintained. This solution has the same effect as using the Language menu to chose the syntax manually; as long as the file is open it will keep its highlighting (even across sessions, iirc), but if you close it you lose the association.

Comment: @kenbellows Did a [little digging](http://superuser.com/questions/40876/assigning-custom-extensions-to-a-languages-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad) and updated the answer with the permanent solution.

Comment: does not work for me as well. I tried to add `css.1` and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not possible (unless someone writes/has written a plugin for it); the entered extension only matches the part of the filename after the last dot as you have found.

So if you enter an extension that includes a dot, it unfortunately doesn't match files with double extensions. But entered extensions that include a dot has a separate behavior that might be useful to some extent: they match the whole filename.

I found this as I use a User Defined Language for the [todo.txt format](https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt). The User Defined Language [specifies the extension as](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/userDefinedLanguages/blob/master/UDLs/TodoDotTxt_byTimDrub.xml) `todo.txt`, and it does match files named exactly `todo.txt`.

I was interested in your question, because I wanted other files to use this language highlighting as well. E.g. I renamed `done.txt` to `done.todo.txt` and created files like `projects.todo.txt`, `2021.todo.txt`, hoping they would use the todo.txt language highlighting, but as you have found out, it doesn't work.

But since I only have a limited number of such filenames, knowing that it can match the whole filename still helped me; I simply added additional extensions, e.g. `done.txt`, `projects.txt`, `2021.todo.txt` etc., for all filenames I would be using. It is still a clunky solution and I would have preferred a way to match all files ending with `.todo.txt` and name my files accordingly; but it works for now and is better than selecting the language every time I reopen the file. (I could have removed the `.txt` part and use `.todo` as the extension as an easier solution, but I wanted to keep `.txt` so that other programs continue to recognize them as text files.)

In your case, this solution is less useful, as you probably have a myriad of different filenames that end with `.css.erb` and `.html.erb`. But it might be still better than nothing if there are files that you work on frequently (`currentproject.css.erb`), or there are common filenames (say `index.html.erb`). You could just add each of those filenames, so that you could avoid having to select language manually at least on those files.